# Simulating Data for Factorial Design of Hormone

Tags: r, simulation, treatment-effect, lm

I am new to simulating data and want feedback on the proposed simulation given the biological relationships I am trying to simulate. Did I make a good model to simulate this data or can it be improved based on the relationships stated below?

Here is the simulation I developed:

```
#######################
# Treatment Variables #
#######################

group<- c(rep(1, 200), rep(2, 200), rep(3, 200), rep(4, 200), rep(5, 
200), rep(6, 200)) 
injection<- c(rep(1, 200), rep(0, 600), rep(1, 400)) 
art_light<- c(rep(1, 400), rep(0, 600), rep(1, 200))
seasonal_light<- c(rep(1, 600), rep(0, 200), rep(1, 200),  rep(1, 200)) 

# Gather data set
dat<- data.frame(group, injection,art_light,seasonal_light)

#################################
# Simulated Response  Variables #
#################################

alpha = 1
beta1 = 10
beta2 = 2
beta3 = 20
beta4 = 10

e1= rnorm(1200, 5, sd=1)
e2 = rlnorm(1200)

dat$hormoneA<-alpha + beta1*injection + beta2*art_light+beta3*seasonal_light+ beta4*injection*seasonal_light+e1
dat$blood<-alpha + beta1*injection + e2
```

The experimental design involves treatments of `injection`, `art_light`, `seasonal_light` to males of a particular animal. These are all presence or absence variables. `injection` is a treatment that stimulates red blood cell production `blood` and is a proxy for the increases in activity during reproduction that stimulate hemoglobin production. `art_light` represents artificial light. `seasonal_light` represents photoperiod which is the seasonal cue necessary for the onset of mating. Continuous measured variables are `blood` and `hormoneA`. `hormoneA` represents a reproductive hormone whose onset of production is initiated when upstream photosensitive receptors are activated by light. The conditions of the different treatment groups applied in this project are specified with the `group` variable.

Information guiding the simulation:

- Presence of `seasonal_light` activates reproduction through a photosensitive receptor that leads to a cascade of events one being the release of the reproductive hormone `hormone A`.
- Changes in physical activity, such as those associated with reproductive activity are associated with increases in the production of `blood`.
- `blood` filters particular wavelengths of light such that increases in blood will enable reproductive-stimulating light frequencies to reach the photo-sensitive receptors. Thus, I would expect more `hormoneA` production in the presence of `injection` (which stimulates `blood` production) such that the light treatments (`seasonal_light` and `art_light`) will have a greater effect on `hormoneA` when `injection` is present.
- Artificial light `art_light` may also have a positive effect on `hormoneA` production since it increases exposure of the photo-sensitive receptors to light. However,  `seasonal_light` is a prerequisite for `hormoneA` such that in the absence of `seasonal_light` there would be no effect of `dim_light` on `hormoneA`, but in the presence of `seasonal_light`, `art_light` would cause small increases in `hormoneA`.

Answer (score 1):

Very interessting subject.
This is not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation here to post a comment.
The way you are simulating suposses that you allready know the relationships between hormone A and others variables (and that you also know that this relationship is linear), and the same for blood.
If so, why is the purpose of your simulation ?
And how did you achieve this knowledge of those kind of relationships, and how do you estimate the coefficients alpha, beta1, beta2 ... ?

Seeing just your code, it seems that the repartition of injection, art_light and seasonnal light is arbitrary.

Do you have some real measurements of thoses variables ? I think it's better to analyse from real observations, and try to find the statistical distributions of your variables, and to model the dependances between them, and after that, if you need some simulations, you could use the distributions and dependances found in order to produce new simulated data.